# redirect to php page from sql server fetch array loop

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to redirect to another php page from sql server fetch array with WHILE loop.
All records are fetched well, but i want to add to the table "delete" link to every fetched record.
I tried the code below separatedly and it works just fine.
The problem is because the code is inside PHP tag and i'm confused with all of the ' ' signs.
while compailing the code below i just can't see nothing (without the "delete" line everything is OK):

```
   while ( $record = sqlsrv_fetch_array($rs, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) )
      {
        $o .= '<tr><td><center>'.$record [0].'</center></td><td><center>'.$record [1].'</center></td>
                   <td><center>'.$record [2].'</center></td><td><center>'.$record [3].'</center></td>
                   <td><center>'.$record [4].'</center></td><td><center>'.$record [5].'</center></td>
                   <td><center>'.$record [6].'</center></td><td><center>'.$record [7].'</center></td>
                   <td>**<a href="JavaScript:if(confirm('delete record?')==true)
                                {window.location='phpSQLServerDeleteRecord.php?EventID=<?php echo $record[0];';}">delete</a>**
                   </tr>';
      }      

       $o .= '</tbody></table>';
       echo $o;
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: If you're asking about the syntax errors, try a heredoc string instead.

Comment: You need to escape your single quotes in your javascript code and properly concat your php code -> `<a href="JavaScript:if(confirm(\'delete record?\')==true){window.location=\'phpSQLServerDeleteRecord.php?EventID='.$record[0].'\';}">delete</a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of single-quotes is creating a syntax error:

```
'</center></td><td>**<a href="JavaScript:if(confirm('delete record?')==true)
 {window.location='phpSQLServerDeleteRecord.php?EventID=<?php echo $record[0];';}">delete</a>**
 </tr>'
```

Since the server-side string literal began with a single quote, as soon as the string *contains* a single-quote then the PHP engine will interpret that as the end of the string, which then results in a couple of syntax errors here as things intended to be part of the string are interpreted as code.

There are a couple of ways to go about this.  One quick fix would be to "escape" the single-quotes which are meant to be part of the string rather than a boundary of the string:

```
'</center></td><td>**<a href="JavaScript:if(confirm(\'delete record?\')==true)
 {window.location=\'phpSQLServerDeleteRecord.php?EventID=<?php echo $record[0];\';}">delete</a>**
 </tr>'
```

Of course, there's still the error that now *PHP code* (the `echo` statement) is being emitted as part of a string.  You can terminate the string boundaries around *that* and concatenate the value to the string like any other string concatenation:

```
'</center></td><td>**<a href="JavaScript:if(confirm(\'delete record?\')==true)
 {window.location=\'phpSQLServerDeleteRecord.php?EventID=' . $record[0] . '\';}">delete</a>**
 </tr>'
```

(Note that immediately after the reference to `$record[0]` there are *two* single-quotes.  One to begin the new string literal and then an escaped one to be the first character in that string literal, since the client-side code will need that single-quote character to terminate *its* string literal.  That's probably the root of your confusion in the matter... These server-side strings aren't just HTML, they're also JavaScript which has its own client-side strings.)

You'll also want to URL-encode that value being emitted as part of a query string (even though it *should* just be a numeric identifier I suspect, it's still good form):

```
'</center></td><td>**<a href="JavaScript:if(confirm(\'delete record?\')==true)
 {window.location=\'phpSQLServerDeleteRecord.php?EventID=' . urlencode($record[0]) . '\';}">delete</a>**
 </tr>'
```

There are a number of other ways to potentially clean this up.  Take a look at [the PHP documentation on strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), particularly around the "heredoc" syntax.  My PHP is to rusty to whip up an example of that, but I suspect it will end up looking a little cleaner in the resulting code.  Either way, it's good to get some practice in the differences between the various ways PHP handle string literals.

Comment: @David Good explanation of WHY he is having the problems he is having.  I think between this and my answer the OP should get the information he needs to clean things up.

Comment: Wow!! works perfect.
Thank you!!
i tried:

<a href="JavaScript:if(confirm(\'delete record?\')==true)
 {window.location=\'phpSQLServerDeleteRecord.php?EventID=' . $record[0] . '\';}">delete</a>

Answer (score 2):

I will echo the comment from @mario above but give you an example of how to use Heredoc syntax to make large blocs of text much more readable and easy to work with, as you will not need to mess with escaping quotes at all.

```
while (...)
{
   $o .= <<<EOT
<tr>
    <td><center>{$record[0]}</center></td>
    <td><center>{$record[1]}</center></td>
    <td><center>{$record[2]}</center></td>
    <td><center>{$record[3]}</center></td>
    <td><center>{$record[4]}</center></td>
    <td><center>{$record[5]}</center></td>
    <td><center>{$record[6]}</center></td>
    <td><center>{$record[7]}</center></td>
    <td>**<a href="JavaScript:if(confirm('delete record?')==true)
        {window.location='phpSQLServerDeleteRecord.php?EventID={$record[0]}}">delete</a>**</td>
</tr>
EOT
}
```

Now doesn't that look a whole lot nicer?

Note: brackets around PHP variables are optional.  I just like them when using Heredoc as I find it makes it easier to see where your variables are.

Read here for more information on Herdoc syntax:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

For future readers, please look to answer by @David as well.  He does good job of explaining why the OP was having his problem. I really look at this answer as complementary to that one, giving the reader an example of what might be a good way to go about solving the problem.